# An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [UserDataS3script] must have values

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am getting errors like below when I am deploying Cloud Formation Template

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [UserDataS3script] must have values
```

My aws command is like below:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file infra/BP-ASG-Product.yml --stack-name ASM-TBV-stack --parameter-overrides LatestLinuxAmiId=ami-xxxxxxxxxxx EnvironmentName=tbv DataClassification=GroupUse AlbSg=sg-rrrrrrrrrrrrr InstanceType=t3.micro AsgSecurityGroups=sg-0176a90063b4fbc3c
```

My *deploy.sh* is like below

```
# !/bin/bash
set -ex

# Purpose:
# ----------
# This script deploys the infrastructure needed for the ASM project.
# This includes the prerequisites and the main infra stacks.

# Arguments:
# ----------
#   Argument               | Description
#   application-name       | Short name of the application
#   environment-name       | Short name for the environment ex: tbv, stg, prod
#   debug                  | Optional. true if you want to enable debug logging, false by default
#   deployment-role-arn    | Optional. Provide the IAM role to use for deployment. This would be needed if deploying cross-account for example.

# Example Usage:
# ----------
# ./deploy.sh --application-name ASM --environment-name tbv --debug true


echo "[START] Deployment started at $(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")"

APPLICATION_NAME=
ENVIRONMENT_NAME=
# ARTIFACTS_BUCKET_CFN_OUTPUT_NAME=ArtifactsBucketName
DEBUG=false

while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    case "$1" in
        --application-name)
            APPLICATION_NAME=$2
            shift ;;
        --environment-name)
            ENVIRONMENT_NAME=$2
            shift ;;
        --debug)
            DEBUG=$2
            shift ;;
        *)
            echo "$1 is not an option"
            exit 1 ;;
    esac
    shift
done

pwd
ls -alrth

export CFN_TEMPLATES_LOCATION=infra/
# export CONFIG_FILE=infra/prerequisites/artifacts-bucket/"${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".parameters.json

# ls -alrth "${CONFIG_FILE}"
pwd

echo "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
echo "${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}"
USER_DATA_SCRIPT_NAME=infra/scripts/user-data-$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M").sh
mv infra/scripts/user-data.sh ${USER_DATA_SCRIPT_NAME}

$DEBUG && echo "DEBUG: APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME"
$DEBUG && echo "DEBUG: ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME"

echo "INFO: Deploying prerequisites stack"
PREREQUISITES_STACK_NAME=${APPLICATION_NAME}-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-prerequisites-stack
$DEBUG && echo "DEBUG: PREREQUISITES_STACK_NAME: ${PREREQUISITES_STACK_NAME}"

export AMI_ID="ami-xxxxxxxxxxx"

echo "INFO: AMI ID: ${AMI_ID}"

echo "INFO: Deploying the main infra stack"
MAIN_INFRA_STACK_NAME=${APPLICATION_NAME}-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-stack
echo "${MAIN_INFRA_STACK_NAME}"
aws cloudformation deploy \
--template-file infra/BP-ASG-Product.yml \
--stack-name ${MAIN_INFRA_STACK_NAME} \
--parameter-overrides "LatestLinuxAmiId=${AMI_ID}" \
  UserDataS3script=${USER_DATA_SCRIPT_NAME} \
$(cat infra/tbv.parameters.properties) 
   "testuser" "xyzhjhsjsjksklsls"
```

What might be the actual issue?

Comment: Your USER_DATA_SCRIPT_NAME is not populated. You can try echoing the value of the variable to make sure it gets populated properly.

Comment: Yep, I did debug the script and fixed it. I also believe that the script was not getting passed. Shell scripting skills plus your lead helped me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing parameters,

Try following:

`aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name MyStack --template-body file://my-template.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=UserDataS3script,ParameterValue=my-s3-script.sh`

Adjust rest of parameters & names acco